# How to create user specific pages (not user role!)?

Tags: user-roles, user-meta, user-registration, user-access

For my users on wordpress I have to manually upload research report for every user. the report is customised and different for every user. I am looking for a way to create user specific page, wherein after login the user is redirected to this page (frontend); and on the backend I can upload relevant report  on this page. Can somebody tell me if this can be achieved by a plugin or customized code?

I understand i can hide-show pages by user role, but dont know if it can be done by a specific user.

Comment: This one got closed, but it has an answer for you, although it's potentially too restrictive. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/336655/restricting-users-to-a-specific-front-end-page