# Restricting users to a specific front end page

Tags: plugins, user-roles

I am looking for a way to restrict users of a certain role to only be able to access one page on my wordpress site. When a user of the role logs in they should be redirected to the page and they should not be able to access any other pages. I have tried multiple plugins that can restrict pages to users, but I have not found one that can restrict users to pages. Does this functionality exist within Wordpress and how would I implement it if it does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to add a function during the `init` action of WP. There you'll get the `current user` and check whether they have a specific `role` assigned to them and `redirect` to the page when they do.

```
add_action('init', function () {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $role = 'your role';

    if (in_array($role, $user->roles)) {
        wp_redirect('url');
    }
});
```

WordPress Function References:

- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/
- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_current_user/
- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/

Relevant SE posts:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36720949/get-user-role-by-id-wordpress